# Turn caching of CSS files in firefox extensions off

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, caching

I'm new to developing Firefox/Chrome extensions and I'm writing an extension that should work for both browsers. In Chrome everything works just fine, but in Firefox, changes I make in CSS files in the extension are only applied when I restart the browser. Somehow the CSS files are cached and Shift + F5 doesn't work either.

I'm injecting the CSS files per JS. Also I've put a pointer to a directory where the extension is instead of building the xpi and installing it. The .js and .css files are hard linked with the files of the Chrome extension if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried using `cssfile.css?[random-value]`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Show code

Comment: Sorry for not providing the code. But since it works with Chrome I thought it's just a setting I need to change. Anyhow, the solution with the random-value works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use these meta to prevent caching

```
<meta http-equiv=”Pragma” content=”no-cache”>
<meta http-equiv=”Expires” content=”-1″>
<meta http-equiv=”CACHE-CONTROL” content=”NO-CACHE”>
```